# Removing Duplicates in Linked List C++ (Seg Faulting)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm not sure why I'm getting this seg fault. I'm thinking it probably has something to do with the list traversal. I'm guessing at the end, it is still trying to traverse but it is seeing a nullptr.

I've tried putting another condition in there to check if nextNode is a nullptr then stop the traversal, but I couldn't get it to work.

What am I missing?

```
void LinkedList::removeDuplicates() 
{
    Node* traverse = m_front;
    Node* nextNode = traverse->getNext();
    Node* duplicate = nullptr;

    if (!isEmpty())
    {
         while(traverse != nullptr)
         {
             if (traverse->getValue() == nextNode->getValue())
             {
                std::cout << "Found duplicate\n";
                duplicate = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode->getNext();

                delete duplicate;
                duplicate = nullptr;

                traverse->setNext(nextNode);
            }

            traverse = nextNode;
            nextNode = nextNode->getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For crashes please include the line number that the crash occurs on as well as the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the list is sorted, otherwise it won't work at all.

If the list is empty, then traverse will be null and the initialization of nextNode will crash.

The last line will also crash, because the last time traverse will be null, and nextnode will be null.

I'd just rearrange nextNode and change the while condition:

```
void LinkedList::removeDuplicates() 
{
    Node* traverse = m_front;
    Node* duplicate = nullptr;

    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        Node* nextNode = traverse->getNext();
        while(nextNode != nullptr)
        {
             if (traverse->getValue() == nextNode->getValue())
             {
                std::cout << "Found duplicate\n";
                duplicate = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode->getNext();

                delete duplicate;
                duplicate = nullptr;

                traverse->setNext(nextNode);
                continue;  // Don't advance again, we already skipped an element.
            }

            traverse = nextNode;
            nextNode = nextNode->getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added continue to avoid problem deleting last element and problem skipping three duplicates in a row.

Comment: Yes, the question assumes that the list is sorted so I didn't worry about implementing the sorting.

Comment: Both the original version, and your proposed solution, will also fail to work correctly if there are more than two duplicate values in a row. For example, if there are three duplicate values in the row, only the second duplicate value will be removed. The list will end up with two duplicate values, the original first one, and the original third one.

Comment: Yep, it will crash.  I was fixing it while you typed the comment I think :)

Comment: Yeah, that still gave me a seg fault.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have all of the code so can't actually test it.... Where is it crashing?